# Equation for a range for a slider

Tags: javascript, algorithm, vue.js, math

I made a range slider in Vue.js

and it takes a min and max value I am assuming as a percentage cause it works from 0 - 100

I need to represent a minimum value of $5000 and a max of $200 000

but I am unfortunately bad a maths and I need the slider to iterate in $1000.

so $5000,$6000,$7000 ... $200 000

How would I calculate this.

```
  <div class="slidecontainer">
    <input  v-model="updateSlider" type="range" min="2.5" max="100.5" class="slider" id="slider" @change="slider(updateSlider)" />
    <div :style="{left: updateSlider + '%'}" id="selector">
        <div class="selector-thumb">
           <p>{{((updateSlider * 1000)*2)}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex">
      <div>
        <p>R5 000</p>
        <p>min</p>
      </div>
      <div style="margin-left:auto">
        <p >R200 000</p>
        <p >max</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

as you can see I took the min value and times it by 1000 and times that value by 2. which is a bit silly and primitive and iterates by 2000, and repesents values from 5000 to 201 000

Comment: You can use `min`, `max` and `step` directly, without converting anything: https://jsfiddle.net/y4qcLwgu/

Answer (score 0):

With Vue you can set `min`, `max`, `step` dynamically also set initial `value`. Please check snippet:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
      min: 5000,
      updateSlider: 10000, //set your initial value
      max: 200000,
      step: 1000
  },
});
```

```css
#slider {
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div class="slidecontainer" id="app">
    <input  v-model="updateSlider" :value="updateSlider" type="range" :min="min" :max="max" :step="step" class="slider" id="slider"/>
    <div :style="{left: updateSlider + '%'}" id="selector">
        <div class="selector-thumb">
           <p>{{updateSlider}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex">
      <div>
        <p>R{{min}}</p>
        <p>min</p>
      </div>
      <div style="margin-left:auto">
        <p >R{{max}}</p>
        <p >max</p>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also check very interesting [vue-slider](https://github.com/NightCatSama/vue-slider-component) library.